# Population size in Fast Messy Genetic Algorithm

Tags: optimization, size, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, population

I'm trying to implement the Fast Messy GA using the paper by Goldberg, Deb, Kargupta Harik: fmGA - Rapid Accurate Optimization of Difficult Problems using Fast Messy Genetic Algorithms.

I'm stuck with the formula about the initial population size to account for the Building Block evaluation noise:

[image: Screenshot from the paper]

The sub-functions here are m=10 order-3(k=3) deceptive functions:

[image: The order-3 sub-function]

l=30, l'=27 and B is signal-to-noise ratio which is the ratio of the fitness deviation to the difference between the best and second best fitness value(30-28=2). Fitness deviation according to the table above is sqrt(155).

However in the paper they say using 10 order-3 subfunctions and using the equation must give you population size 3,331 but after substitution I can't reach it since I am not sure what is the value of c(alpha).

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out what exactly is c(alpha). At least the graph drawing it against alpha looks exactly the same as in the paper. It seems by the square of the ordinate they mean the square of the Z-score found by Inverse Normal Random Distribution using alpha as the right-tail area. At first I was missleaded that after finding the Z-score it should be substituted in the Normal Random Distribution equation to fight the height(ordinate).

There is some implementation in Lua here https://github.com/xenomeno/GA-Messy for the interested folks. However the Fast Messy GA has some problems reproducing the figures from the original Goldberg's paper which I am not sure how to fix but these is another matter.